# misplaced output when printing array

Tags: php, debugging

I was debugging some code and when I tried to print the data in a readable way,
it got displayed very odd ...

```
echo "<br />users:" . print_r($users);
echo "<br />items:" . print_r($items);
```

The result was this:

```
Array ( ) 
users:1Array ( ) 
items:1
```

Why is the result array displayed before the string "users:"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_r` directly prints to stdout. The execution order here is:

1. `print_r` to stdout
2. `return true`
3. concatenate your string with `true` (becomes `1`)
4. `echo` the concatenated string to stdout

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `print_r()` inside and echo, you have to tell `print_r()` to defer its output like this

```
echo "<br />users:" . print_r($users,true);
echo "<br />items:" . print_r($items,true);
```

> The [manual for print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)